# Как вывести сообщение используя thymeleaf

Tags: java

Есть такой код:

```html
if (userFromDb != null) {
model.put("message", "Такой пользователь существует!");
return "registration"; 
}
```

Как вывести сообщение "Такой пользователь существует!", используя шаблонизатор thymeleaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так

```
<p>[[${message} ? ${message} : '']]</p>
```